# Unable to convert cyrillic to latin-oracle db

Tags: oracle

When I run SQL command to return all info about the database settings I get this

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET    CL8MSWIN1251
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   10.2.0.4.0
```

SO when I execute SQL query, I get one column with weird characters, something like "ї".

What I tried is the code below but no success:

```
select convert(fname, 'UTF8', 'CL8MSWIN1251') firstname 
from users;
```

Can anyone help me?

PS. the data in this field is in cyrillic (macedonian)

Comment: Maybe use TRANSLATE function instead convert?

Comment: Where do you make your query? In SQL*Plus or any other tool? Usually translation or convert is not required.

Comment: i am using plsql, but if i change some language preferences, that will be only locally, and this query will be used from other people too thats why i need to translate or convert it somehow